# Translation of a poem, gerund form of 加速

Tags: translation, verbs

I have to translate this poem in chinese:

I am still alive, right here and now //
Speeding up immobile in the tangible matter //
I dream the eternal life or death

I found this translation, but I am not sure that this doesn't sound wrong or un-natural. Doesn't the gerund have its translation, doesn't the sense change in this way?

我还活着，就在此时此地  //
在有形的以太中加速不动  //
我梦想着永恒的生或死

Comment: matter = 物质 -->  在有形物质中加速不动

Answer (score 1):

I am still alive, right here and now，
此时此地的我依然是有生命的，
Speeding up immobile in the tangible matter
在这充满形态的物质世界里以静加速，
I dream the eternal life or death
我梦想着永生或是永久的消亡。
Who am I?
我是谁？

Answer (score 1):

My humble offering, with a big dash of poetic licence.

此时此地,还着活,

物质中内,速不移;

永恒梦想,生或死,

暗自又问,我是谁.

Comment: probably `此时此地`, `还活着`,

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, but I did the deliberate switch for "poetic effect" :)